# how to setting keepalived on GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying Google Compute Engine with 6 instances. 4 instances for Galera Cluster. 2 instances for haproxy and keepalived. Setting up for Galera cluster and haproxy --> finished.

But, How to setting keepalived --> virtual ip.
I already set static ip on virtual_ip_address, but 4 instances (Galera cluster) can not access to virtual_ip_address.

Please show me how to set up keepalived on GCE.

Thanks.